# Is there a library/function to generate sentences with input key phrases or words?

Tags: python, string, list

Consider this sentence:

"get me average order rate for Samsung" -> We can break this sentence into key phrases like:

```
<action> <aggregate> <metric> <preposition> <organisation/brand> [1]
```

Now for each of the key phrase we could have a list of names/inputs. For example:

```
action -> ["get me", "find me", "what is", ...]
aggregate -> ["average", "net", "total", "mean", ...]
metric -> ["order rate", "request rate", "revenue", "profit",...]
preposition ->["for", "of",...]
organisation/brand -> ["Samsung", "ESPN", "Johnnie Walker" ...]
```

Is there a way to generate sentences which follow the order of [1] by using all combinations of  key phrase names/inputs?
Appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: hey ,sorry about that, wanted some kind of headway or advice though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For brute-force generating all possible combinations from some lists you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools

actions = ["get me", "find me", "what is"]
aggregates = ["average", "net", "total", "mean"]
metrics = ["order rate", "request rate", "revenue", "profit"]
prepositions = ["for", "of"]
organisations = ["Samsung", "ESPN", "Johnnie Walker"]

sentence_format = "{action} {aggregate} {metric} {preposition} {organisation}"

# go through each possible combination
for action, aggregate, metric,preposition, organisation in itertools.product(actions, aggregates, metrics, prepositions, organisations):
    print(sentence_format.format(**locals())) # pass the values from the product
```

Which gives you:

```
get me average order rate for Samsung
get me average order rate for ESPN
get me average order rate for Johnnie Walker
get me average order rate of Samsung
get me average order rate of ESPN
...
what is mean profit for ESPN
what is mean profit for Johnnie Walker
what is mean profit of Samsung
what is mean profit of ESPN
what is mean profit of Johnnie Walker
```